# Sveltekit deploy on a custom domain

Tags: build, hosting, sveltekit

I don't know which files or folders upload to my custom domain hosting

I tried upload the output folder, the client folder that sveltekit generates I only want to upload the app like the photo that is a simple website [image: what I would like to..]

And what I have...
[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figure out!
What i want is called static site, lol i know maybe si basic so researching i found this "adapter" that build sveltekit to a folder with files like a common website heres the link https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static